# JavaL Different Big Decimal values converted to UTF-8 Strings have the same value

Tags: java, utf-8, bigdecimal

As part of having fun with Avro, I discovered the following:

```
new String(new BigDecimal("1.28").unscaledValue().toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
.equals(
new String(new BigDecimal("1.29").unscaledValue().toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
-> true !!!!!!!!


DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(new BigDecimal("1.28").unscaledValue().toByteArray())
.equals(
DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(new BigDecimal("1.29").unscaledValue().toByteArray()))
-> false (as expected)
```

but

```
new String(new BigDecimal("1.26").unscaledValue().toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
.equals(
new String(new BigDecimal("1.27").unscaledValue().toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")))
-> false (as expected)
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on? Seems like 1.27 is the cuttoff. 
Ideally, I need

```
new String(new BigDecimal("1.28").unscaledValue().toByteArray(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
```

to work for every BigDecimal value.

Comment: Do you mind just adding the output of printing those unscaled values? (too lazy this morning to run it myself ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me what is going on?

Yes, you're misusing your data. The result of `BigDecimal.toByteArray()` is *not* a UTF-8-encoded representation of a string, so you shouldn't try to convert it to a string that way.

*Some* different byte arrays may be "decoded" to strings via UTF-8 as the same, if they're basically invalid. If you look at the result of `new BigDecimal("1.28").unscaledValue().toByteArray()` and likewise for 1.29, you'll find that they're invalid, so both decode to strings containing "?". However, if you're doing this *at all* then you're doing it wrong.

The two byte arrays in question are { 0x00, 0x80 } and { 0x00, 0x81 }. The first byte of that will be decoded to U+0000, and the second byte of it is the *start* of a UTF-8-encoding of a character, but it's incomplete - so the decoder uses `?`. So both strings are `"\0?"`.

If you want to convert a `BigDecimal` to a string, just call `toString()`. If you want to represent *arbitrary binary data* as a string, use base64 or hex, or some similar encoding scheme *designed* to represent arbitrary binary data as strings. UTF-8 is designed to represent arbitrary *text* data as binary data.

Comment: Thanks ! Do you see me potentially running into this issue if I use Latin 1 encoding ? It seems that my code works when I use it

Comment: @Stephane: Yes, you'll end up with control characters that may well cause problems down the line. **This is not encoded text data. Don't treat it as if it were.** This is precisely the situation that base64 and hex are provided for. Use them.